# Obtain Duplicated Data

Tags: sql-server

Please suggest an SQL query to find duplicate customers across different stores, e.g. customer table has id, name, phone, storeid in it, I need to write queries for the following:

1. Duplicate customers within a store
2. Duplicate customers across different stores

Table data:

```
id    name      phone       storeid
-----------------------------------    
1     abc        123       4
2     abc        123       4
3     abc        123       5
```

The first query should **show only first 2** records, and the second query should show **all 3** records.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged?cb=1

Comment: Use group by and having...

Comment: @Isaiah - please don't answer questions in the comments... there is no way for the asker to mark the answer as correct and therefore people like me come here, read and then discover there is nothing to be done whereas once it is flagged as answered I know I can ignore it. I could be helping someone else.

Comment: @nik - Read [How to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - for starters you should be showing what you have already tried.

Comment: @GB At the time, I was giving a terse answer because I did not feel like writing a full answet, but I have now fixed that and submitted a complete answer with code and explanation. Furthermore, I removed the two answer-comments.

Comment: @nik You have done a fairly good job at writing a question, but here's some suggestions: use proper grammar, spelling, and mechanics; provide anything you have tried before (we normally do not do stuff for you); and provide a more precise and longer expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:-

```
SELECT Name,Phone, COUNT(Id) NumberOfTimes, StoreID
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Name,Phone,StoreID
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
ORDER BY StoreID
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding an explanation is useful to future visitors

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT storeName, customerName FROM customer
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT c.storeid
  FROM customer 'c'
  RIGHT JOIN store 's' ON (c.storeid = s.id)
  GROUP BY c.storeid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Basically, we are grouping by storeids, which allows us to count the times they occur in the customer table. We get the id of a case where there are multiple occurrences, and we select the storeName and CustomerName from the customer table that contains the id we got from the inner query.

Comment: I'm of the assumption that you're assuming that id is storeid, yet I am led to believe id is really the autoincrement, unique primary key which would invalidate this answer

Comment: Yes id is autoincrement. However I was under the assumption that storeid is the customer's table's way for joining to store's id, which I think is a fair assumption. However, the question doesn't make it too clear so it's possible this may need to be modified as you point out.

Comment: Storeid can repear; autoincrement doesnt

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can try this for the first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer,
WHERE 1 < (
  SELECT COUNT(name)
  FROM customer
  WHERE name IN (
    SELECT name FROM customer
  )
) AND
1 < (
  SELECT COUNT(storeid)
  FROM customer
  WHERE storeid IN (
    SELECT storeid FROM customer
  )
);
```

Now, for the second query, use the above one, but remove everything after and including the `AND`.

### Explanation

Let's look at the query step-by-step:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
```

This is stating you want all the columns from the customers table.

```
WHERE 1 < (
  SELECT COUNT(name)
  FROM customer
  WHERE name IN (
    SELECT name FROM customer
  )
)
```

This is a pretty long query, so let's look from inside-outward.

```
  WHERE name IN (
    SELECT name FROM customer
  )
```

This time we're getting all the names of customers and checking if their is match in our curret table. To be truthful, we might not need this whole section....

```
  SELECT COUNT(name)
  FROM customer
```

This is stating we want the total number of times each name appears (count) in the customers table that matches the where clause.

```
WHERE 1 < (
  ....
)
```

Here, we are comparing the result from the subquery (the number of duplicated names) and checking to see if it is greater than l (i.e., there is a duplicate).

```
AND
.....
```

The `AND` keyword indicates that this second condition must **be true** ***in addition*** to the previous conditions.

The full query should return all entries where both the names **and** store ids are duplicated; if you remove everything including and after the `AND`, that will result in all entries which have the same name, but not neccessarily the right store id.

### Notes

The other two answers are suggesting grouping duplicated data, but in your particular case, I think you **do** want the duplicated entries as per your expected results (albeit you should add more expected output info than that).